# Issue with creating the function in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having issues with implementing a function. It seems like that the syntax is not getting write.
Here's my different versions of code. None of them seems to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F1 (DTE IN VARCHAR(50))
RETURN VARCHAR(50) IS
B1 VARCHAR(50);
SELECT * INTO B1 FROM DUAL;
RETURN B1
END
```

Even the below template phrase isnt working

```
 create or replace function compute()
  2  return varchar2
  3  is
  4  begin
  5  end;
  6  /
```

Heres the error

> ```
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
>          following:
>          ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
>          raise return select update while with <an identifier>
>          <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
> ```

Maybe i am just missing some small thing.

Comment: Thanks APC, will surely do that. Yes it's trivial though I had tried few examples of other recommendations through different sites but that din help earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues(see inline comments in the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F1 (DTE IN VARCHAR) -- size is not needed here
RETURN VARCHAR IS -- size is not needed here
B1 VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN -- begin keyword is needed here
SELECT <some_column> INTO B1 FROM DUAL; -- column name instead of *
RETURN B1; -- ; is needed here
END; -- ; is needed here
```

Comment: Thanks Tejash bro, I will surely check this code tomorrow. I know I may have done something  wrong with the syntax itself

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first code lacks a ';' at the end of the last 2 lines.
your second sample needs somethings between the begin and end:

```
create or replace function compute()
 return varchar2
 is
 begin
   return 'a';
 end;
 /
```

Comment: You're right, have to remove them. I just did a cut-and-paste to show where are the errors in the body, and did not pay attention to the ().

Comment: Thanks gsalem I will surely check this tomorrow